# Structure of player score table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datatable

I have a need to migrate game score table from (don't laugh please...) *.ini *database* to SQL tables, as I want to migrate the whole game to MySQL base.

The need is to store user scores in database, to be able retrive result tables for overall/year/mont/week/day time spans. That takes each year: {year score} + {month score}*12 + {week score}*52 + {day score}*360 = ~425 rows per user + 1 {overall score} row per user. That does not feel optimized, that is why I am here with this question.

What base to use? Mentioned above, is base for timespans, using structure like this:

```
{timespan type} {timespan} {user ID} {score for type 1} {score for type 1} {score for type 1} {score for type 2}
```

Another thing that I need to note. There are different methods for different score types, to sort. If first type is plain score, where I take highest (more - better), then second type is speed, where I sort by fastest speed (smaller - better).

If you have question: "Why seperate rows for weeks/months/years/overall?", then answer is, that I want some fast way to get a results table, for example, for last weeks score type 2, first 3 places.

I was thinking, maybe, if I store only {day score}, getting rid of those 426-360=66 rows per user in current structure, leading to new structure:

```
{user ID} {day number} {score for type 1} {score for type 1} {score for type 1} {score for type 2}
```

How will I get out "First 3 places for best score in speed, for previous week". That would take some multi-level calculations...

1. Query for rows with days, that goes into time span for previous weeks for ALL users
2. Sum all scores for each {user ID} or get lowest score (depending on score type) and put in a new table
3. Query new table, sorting by score column ASC or DESC (depending on score type) and retreive first 3 rows
4. Repeat steps 2. & 3. for each score column

If I want to do that more than 1-3 times a minute (as after each new input in table, I need to evaluate, how much points for specific user is to get in higher standing, I imagine, that would take some serious server resources. As of structure given at top of question (timespan base), that only takes step 3. for each score column.

Thanks for answers & suggestions!

The current format of data follows:

```
Overall file: overall.ini
(in folder of yearnumber) Year file: 2011.ini
(in folder of yearnumber) Month files: m1.ini ... m12.ini
(in folder of yearnumber) Week files: n1.ini ... n52.ini
(in folder of yearnumber) Day files: m1d1.ini ... m12d1.ini
```

Data stored inside:

```
[~REZ~]
User13245325=1145 203.433 3 1.735
User3425435=1412 173.871 8 2
User32487854=18 76.253 1 11.016
User345645=2153 155.139 8 2.344
User65875=100 67.767 2 10.016
User453325=26 138.568 1 3.031
```

PS: This is general question, not directly related to game development, so please, dont toss it away to gamedevelopment SO section.

Comment: Could you post some data from what you currently have stored in inifiles. It might clear up some things. As it is, I find your question(s) to hard to follow. Looking at the effort you've clearly put in and the lack of answers, so do others.

Comment: @Lieven Check edit, I have included current data formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I am really struggling to understand what you're asking here - but if I understand correctly, there's some other system in which the actual game outcomes are recorded, and you want to turn that game data into a leaderboard-style data structure, and you want your queries to run really, really fast.

So, first off - you seem to worry about the size of your data. Unless you're dealing with absolutely astronomical scale (Google, Facebook, Twitter), you probably don't need to. Disk space is cheap, and a well-indexed database is just as quick with millions of rows as it is with dozens.

Broadly speaking, you need to decide whether you're going to trade space (pre-computing the results) for speed, and when you're going to do the calculations.

In general, working with "raw" data and computing the results at run time is the easiest to understand and maintain, and has the lowest risk of bugs - but is also likely to be the slowest. Nevertheless, that's where I'd start. You don't give an indication of how your "raw" data is stored, or how frequently it updates, but I'd start by writing a query that produces your intended data. If it's tricky, I'd factor some of the intermediate steps into views to simplify the query.

Then, I'd measure performance, using a load testing tool (JMeter or similar is perfect).

If - but only if - it's really too slow, I'd start by gradually turning the views into pre-computed tables, by introducing regular batch jobs to populate those views. This depends entirely on your data and how "stale" it's allowed to be.

You can usually get very good performance gains out of this approach - and the solution remains fairly simple and resistant to bugs, as long as the batch jobs run...

Only when that approach runs into performance bottlenecks would I consider pre-computing the whole data set. In that case, you may as well create a table that is exactly like the one you want to output to the screen.

Comment: Ok, if I stop worry about storage and speed of execution. What is the most basic structure, I should start with? Basically, this those scores come in format of '{date} {user Id} {score type1..type4}'.

Comment: +1 not much to add here. AFAICT, you could suffice with one table and three columns: Username, Timestamp & Score. With that you could produce all the results you need and keep it easy to maintain.

Comment: @Lieven You mean, like logfiles? {timestamp} {user id} {score}?

Comment: @Deele, pretty much yes. If you see a problem with that, let us know what you think the problem is so we can come up with solutions without needing to change your structure (or adapt the structure).

Comment: @Lieven If I take log'file approach, that would take too much space. The scores are added pretty frequently (up to 5 times in a minute), that would generate at max ~2 600 000 entries a year. After reading all of your answers, I think, I will construct some sort of **{timestamp with year+month+date} {user Id} {scores}** and will try to make queries, for getting result tables, as I need, resulting in **{2011.04.11} {user 1} {123}** and **{2011.04.11} {user 2} {124}** and **{2011.04.10} {user 1} {56}**

Comment: @Deele, you know best at what granularity you need to store the data. Beware though that if you don't store your data with enough level of detail, there is no way to get the detail back in afterwards. Starting with (to much?) detail leaves all options open. You could run for 20 years and still not have to much data for MySQL to handle.

Comment: @Lieven Ok then, I test, using logfile style, I could eaven add more columns, with specific data, that was not stored previously. But using that system, would be good only for new data, old data wont have such a detail (as you said, no way to get the detail back in now).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest 2 tables.

user, with associated user info, and score with score info.

score would look like:

```
score
------
user_id
speed
score_total
```

all your aggregations can easily be done with a query.